# KeyboardInterrupt --> int object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I'm trying "try...finally" and I wrote a very simple program:

```
try:
    while True:
       print("hi")
finally:
       print("goodbye")
```

When I do Ctrl+C (KeyboardInterrupt) I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/francesco/Documenti/prova.py", line 3, in <module>
 print("hi")
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1344, in write
 return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I did further tests (with & without try-finally, with while & for, with print and with a counter) and I found that it's a problem of KeyboardInterrupt (I always get "object is not callable" or similar).

Keep in mind that the programs work as expected (the "finally" piece does his job).

I'm using python 3.

What I should do? Why I get this error?

Thanks for your answers and patience!

Comment: Do you want it to print 'goodbye' after you type Ctrl+C? Please be specific with your question.

Comment: I don't know but this looks like a bug in Python's IDLE shell.

Comment: "idlelib" -- are you using IDLE ?